# Testcases failing in azure pipeline giving error edge driver exception

Tags: rest, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

```
Microsoft Edge WebDriver was started successfully.
      org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of Microsoft Edge WebDriver only supports Microsoft Edge version 111
Current browser version is 122.0.2365.92 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe
```

First few test cases in running in azure pipeline pass and rest of the testcases start filing giving this error?

I tried updating the edge driver multiple times but no success

Comment: Please show us the minimal code example to reproduce this issue.